# A way to save the generated HTML from Django Views?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save all the HTML pages from the model objects I'm querying.

For instance for every model_id I have in the database, I want to save the http://127.0.0.1:8080/model_id.

I'm currently connecting to the local server shown above, and pinging through every http://127.0.0.1:8080/#id1, http://127.0.0.1:8080/#id2, http://127.0.0.1:8080/#id600, etc.

Is there a way I can get the html without using the local server to query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Django test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client). The response's [`content`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.content) contains the html of the page.

```
from django.test import Client
c = Client()
response = c.get('/mymodel/1')
content = response.content
```

Comment: I had to use `response = c.get('/foo/bar/')`, so I wouldn't need to connect to a server.